# Как реализовать систему рангов

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Вот код, дальше не знаю как писать

```
print("Check..")
```

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
 
import sqlite3
from Cybernator import Paginator as pag
import pendulum
import random
import asyncio
import datetime
import os
import  time
from discord import FFmpegPCMAudio

from discord.utils import get
import youtube_dl
import cogs
print("Successfully!")

base = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
cursor = base.cursor()

class lvlsystem(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, ctx):
        ran = random.randint(1, 3)
        gg = 50 * 1.5
        cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET 1lvl = 1lvl + {} WHERE id = {}".format(ran, ctx.author.id))
        base.commit()
        if cur.execute("SELECT 1lvl FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(ctx.author.id)).fetchone()[0] == 50:
            cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET lvl = lvl + {} WHERE id = {}".format(1, ctx.author.id))
 
def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(lvlsystem(client))
```

Comment: 1) Вы как-то очень странно код разместили. Я исправил - исправляйте дальше, если он не так выглядит, как должно. Первая строка особо странная с `print("Check..")` 2) Что у вас за ситема рангов - для меня загадка, так как она не описана. Но, может, её понимают знатоки `discord`. Тогда комментарий 2 игнорируйте.

Comment: print("Check..") это проверка модулей